# VBScript Classic: ASP Pool Array from Dictionary, I get type mismatch ('800a000d')

Tags: arrays, dictionary, asp-classic

I am storing multidimensional array in a Dictionary, e.g. *Dic "myKey", Array(1, 10)* so it will be two columns, and 11 rows array.

I store it like this:

```vb
Dic.Add myKey, arrayVariable
```

Then I wish to get back my Array:

```vb
arrayVariable = Dic("myKey")
```

This line gives the error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'  
Type mismatch
```

If I send the array `Dic("myKey")` to a function that will loop through it, it is working fine, however pulling the array from the dictionary, I get the error.

My mission is to store in the Dictionary a key, and a multidimensional array.
The array, have two numeric columns.

I wish to have a sort functionality by the second column, but keep the first one intact.

I don't care to use any of the types, Array, ArrayList, or any other object that can do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dimension of my variables, I declared the Array like this:

```vb
Dim Arr()
```

Then ReDim it (with and without Preserve).

When I let any function return an array, and set it to the Arr variable, I got an error. But, when I remove the parenthesis and declare it like this:

```vb
Dim Arr
ReDim Arr(cols, rows)
```

It solves the error.

Comment: This has been covered before, you must make sure when using a dynamic array declaration to always set the initial size using `ReDim Preserve`. Until you do you do not have a valid array hence the `Type mismatch` error. See [Technet - Creating Dynamic Arrays](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198862.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I wrote something else, but someone (Lankymart) changed it. The Answer above is not my answer and is out of the context.

Comment: Actually @shadow-wizard changed your text by taking out blurb which shouldn't be included like signatures and thank you's. For future reference before pointing fingers you can view the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28976940/revisions) by clicking the `edited ... hours ago` link above the last user to make a revision to the post. If you are not satisfied with this explanation you can also go and raise your concern on [meta].

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I saw that. I saw a change in the original question, then you right.
As I said, he change the meaning of what I said.
I wrote that in the declaration you need to remove the parenthesis, but he wrote that you can redim with or without preserve.
if you a programmer you know it is a big different.
Anyhow, it is not my issue today, as I have solved it.
My apology if you got offended.

Comment: That's fine I'm just not big on finger pointing. The edits didn't change your answer, the solution is still the same just unneeded noise was removed. The only edit I made was to add the proper code syntax highlighting using the `<!-- language: lang-vb -->` SO markdown syntax. For more information about why your post was edited refer here - [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) *(look at **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.**)*

Comment: Believe me, with 15 years of experience in classic ASP I can assure you I did not change the meaning, just removed noise and improved formatting, to match something I could have answered myself.

Comment: accept my apology.
I just marked this one to be the right answer.
I am over this error, and stuck with others (a life of a programmer).